# How can I connect to a Tor hidden service using cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, tor

I'm trying to connect to a Tor hidden service using the following PHP code:

```
$url = 'http://jhiwjjlqpyawmpjx.onion/'
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://127.0.0.1:9050/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
print_r($curl_error);
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> Couldn't resolve host name

However, when I run the following command from my command line in Ubuntu:

```
curl -v --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 http://jhiwjjlqpyawmpjx.onion
```

I get a response as expected.

The PHP [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) documentation says this:

```
--socks5-hostname
Use  the  specified  SOCKS5 proxy (and let the proxy resolve the host name).
```

I believe the reason it works from the command line is because Tor (the proxy) is resolving the .onion hostname, which it recognizes. When running the PHP code above, my guess is that cURL or PHP is trying to resolve the .onion hostname and doesn't recognize it. I've searched for a way to tell cURL/PHP to let the proxy resolve the hostname, but I can't find a way.

There is a very similar Stack Overflow question, *[cURL request using socks5 proxy fails when using PHP, but it works through the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944067)*.

Answer (score 120):

You need to set the `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE` option to [`CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php)

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);
```

`CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME` is defined [starting with PHP 5.6.10](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69950). If you're using an older version you can explicitly use its value, `7`:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
```

Answer (score 23):

I use [Privoxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privoxy) and cURL to scrape Tor pages:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init('http://jhiwjjlqpyawmpjx.onion'); // Tormail URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "localhost:8118"); // Default privoxy port
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

After installing Privoxy you need to add this line to the configuration file (`/etc/privoxy/config`). Note the space and '.' a the end of line.

```
forward-socks4a / localhost:9050 .
```

Then restart Privoxy.

```
/etc/init.d/privoxy restart
```

Comment: This works! Tested on both Windows 10 and CentOS 6, also if Tor uses Socks 5 instead of Socks 4, use this: `forward-socks5 / localhost:9150 .`

Answer (score 9):

Try to add this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
```

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: Set `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE` to use `CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME` if you have a modern PHP, the value `7` otherwise, and/or correct the `CURLOPT_PROXY` value.

As you correctly deduced, you cannot resolve `.onion` domains via the normal DNS system, because this is [a reserved top-level domain specifically for use by Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.onion) and such domains by design have no IP addresses to map to.

Using `CURLPROXY_SOCKS5` will direct the cURL command to send its traffic to the proxy, but will *not* do the same for domain name resolution. The DNS requests, which are emitted *before* cURL attempts to establish the actual connection with the Onion site, will still be sent to the system's normal DNS resolver. These DNS requests will surely fail, because the system's normal DNS resolver will not know what to do with a `.onion` address unless it, too, is specifically forwarding such queries to Tor.

Instead of `CURLPROXY_SOCKS5`, you must use [`CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE.html). Alternatively, you can also use `CURLPROXY_SOCKS4A`, but SOCKS5 is much preferred. Either of these proxy types informs cURL to perform both its DNS lookups and its actual data transfer via the proxy. This is required to successfully resolve any `.onion` domain.

There are also two additional errors in the code in the original question that have yet to be corrected by previous commenters. These are:

- Missing semicolon at end of line 1.
- The proxy address value is set to an HTTP URL, but its type is SOCKS; these are incompatible. For SOCKS proxies, the value must be an IP or domain name and port number combination without a scheme/protocol/prefix.

Here is the correct code in full, with comments to indicate the changes.

```php
<?php
$url = 'http://jhiwjjlqpyawmpjx.onion/'; // Note the addition of a semicolon.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050"); // Note the address here is just `IP:port`, not an HTTP URL.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME); // Note use of `CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME`.
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
print_r($curl_error);
```

You can also omit setting `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE` entirely by changing the `CURLOPT_PROXY` value to include the `socks5h://` prefix:

```php
// Note no trailing slash, as this is a SOCKS address, not an HTTP URL.
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_PROXY, 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to help you.
Tho to save time first of all you need to make sure that you check if the proxy is valid to not with simple check with fsocketopen()

```
        try {
            $fp = fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10);
            fclose($fp);
            return true;
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return false;
        }
```

If socket returns true then go for requestUrl function

```
    private function requestUrl($url, $proxy)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        $contents = curl_exec($curl);
        //Check for errors.
        // if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        //     return new \Exception(curl_error($curl));
        // }
        curl_close($curl);
        return $contents;
    }
```