# How to Build and Send an HTTP Request to a Tor Hidden Service with Ruby

Tags: ruby, tor

I've spent the last couple of days looking for a solution to this problem, and though there are quite a few semi-relevant questions, none of the answers show a successful use case for sending a successful HTTP request over Tor to a hidden service using Ruby.

One thing that seems unclear in all the answers is how the Tor browser bundle acts as a proxy for requests.

I've tried multiple avenues of attack, the most recent being an attempt to adapt [the PHP code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445285/how-can-i-connect-to-a-tor-hidden-service-using-curl-in-php) for sending curl requests to hidden services using Ruby CURL libraries.

This is my code using the Curb gem, which implements some of the libcurl bindings for Ruby:

```
require 'curb'

url = 'http://am4wuhz3zifexz5u.onion' #a known, functioning hidden service

c = Curl::Easy.new(url) do |curl| 
  curl.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" #the user agent string from the most recent version of the tor browser
  curl.verbose = true
end

c.perform
c.inspect
```

I then tried to run this through socksify, using the IP address and port specified by the Tor browser bundle's proxy settings:

```
$ socksify_ruby 127.0.0.1 9150 tor-test/tor-test.rb
```

This produced the following output:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fb1fe195e00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fb1fe195e00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Could not resolve host: jhiwjjlqpyawmpjx.onion
* Closing connection 0
```

Every approach I've tried has produced a similar result: **the URI for the hidden service cannot be resolved**

Can anyone help me out here or point me in the right direction? I feel that since the Tor browser can connect programmatically to hidden services, we all should be able to as well : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curl only uses a proxy if you set it up in your "curl"-block.

For example:

```
c = Curl::Easy.new() do |curl| 
    curl.proxy_tunnel = true
    curl.proxy_type = Curl::CURLPROXY_SOCKS5 # also available and default Curl::CURLPROXY_HTTP
    curl.proxy_url = '127.0.0.1:9050' # local tor client/proxy
    curl.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" #the user agent string from the most recent version of the tor browser
    curl.verbose = true
    curl.url = url # your example url
    curl.perform
    curl.inspect
end
```

Unfortunately curl does not use the proxy for hostname resolution. In other words, I did't find a way to force curl to use the proxy for hostname resolution.

But you can try

```
#enable socksify debug
Socksify::debug = true

#own try via direct use of socksify and Net::HTTP
uri = URI.parse('http://am4wuhz3zifexz5u.onion/') #a known, functioning hidden service

# some debug stuff - just ignore ;-)
puts uri
puts uri.host
puts uri.port
puts uri.path

res1 = Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy('127.0.0.1', 9050).start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http| 
    http.get(uri.path)
end
```

Comment: I was eventually able to get this to work using a similar solution to what you suggested with Socksify. A large part of the issue was a misunderstanding of the Tor client. Making a connection and resolving .onion domains was trivial once the Tor client was set up properly.

Comment: Since curl 7.14.1 you can specify the proxy host string including protocol. So `curl.proxy_url = 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'` does the trick as 5h tells curl to resolve host names through the socks proxy too. It is documented in the curb gem here: https://github.com/taf2/curb/blob/a44fe433dd48382da88c67d6b0817dbdcd86bd79/lib/curl/easy.rb#L153